# How to Create a postgresql database from a PHP form

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I'm working in a web app with PHP and Postgresql. I`m looking for a PHP code to create a database online using a PHP form that sends the name, template, UTF8, etc.

Something like this for MYSQL but for with Postgresql:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: All you really need to do is find a Postgres driver. The rest of it's pretty much the same, both Postgres and MySQL tend to hew close to the standard.